# Trouble using mount.cifs to mount a share drive on a local network after updating packages

Tags: linux, mount, network-shares, samba

Currently I have a computer running Arch linux `6.3.3-arch1-1`. After running a system update with `pacman -Syu` about a month ago I have been unable to mount my network share drive, which is in my `/etc/fstab` as follows:

```
//192.168.0.162/share /mnt/share    cifs username=anonymous,password=,vers=1.0,rw,forcegid,gid=984,forceuid,uid=1000   0 0
```

prior to doing the system update I had no issue with this line in my `/etc/fstab`.
When I run `mount.cifs` from the command line with the same argument I get the following

```
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
Checking the kernel log gives me the somewhat vague entry
[861746.528145] CIFS: VFS: Use of the less secure dialect vers=1.0 is not recommended unless required for access to very old servers
[861746.528148] CIFS: Attempting to mount \\192.168.0.162\share
[861746.563744] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
```

My `mount.cifs` is the following version:

```
mount.cifs version: 7.0
```

my `/mnt/share` folder has the following permissions

```
$ ls /mnt
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 2022-10-17 14:08 share
```

Is there anything anyone knows about what is going on or any information I could provide to help trouble shoot this issue? My share drive is a Buffalo TeraStation

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by changing the smb version to version 2

```
//192.168.0.162/share /mnt/share cifs username=anonymous,password=,vers=2.0,rw,forcegid,gid=984,forceuid,uid=1000 0 0
```